Prove that if G is 4-ordered Hamiltonian graph, then G is 3-connected
The definition of a k-ordered Hamiltonian graph:

A Hamiltonian graph $G$ of order $n$ is $k$-ordered Hamiltonian for an integer $k$ with $1≤k≤n$
if for every ordered set S=${v_1,v_2,⋯,v_k}$ of $k$ vertices of $G$, there is a Hamiltonian cycle of $G$ encountering these $k$ vertices of S in the order listed

I decided that I could try to prove this by contradiction.
Assume that graph $G$ is $4$-ordered Hamiltonian graph which is $1$ or $2$-connected. Then the vertex connectivity number  $\kappa(G)$ = $1$ or $\kappa(G)$ = $2$.
Since G is Hamiltonian, there is a Hamiltonian cycle $C$ thus  $\kappa(G)$ cannot be $1$.
Assume then that $\kappa(G)$ = $2$.
From Whitney's theorem, we know that $ \kappa \leq \kappa' \leq \delta $
then  $ 2 \leq \kappa' \leq \delta $
And I got stuck here.
My other was idea was to avoid proof by contradiction and use another Whitney's theorem which claims that there are $k$-disjoint paths in every $k$-connected graph. But I don't really know how I'd go on about proving the statement that I want to prove.
Any hints/tips?

Are you familiar with Menger's theorem?

@MathieuRundström, yes, I am.

Menger's theorem implies that if between any pair of vertices in $G$ there are $k$ internally disjoint paths, then $G$ is $k$-connected.
Let $G$ be $4$-ordered Hamiltonian, and let $u, v\in V(G)$. We show there are three internally disjoint $uv$-paths. Let $w, w'\in V(G)$ be distinct from $u, v$. Such vertices exist since $4\leq |V(G)|$ by assumption. By definition, there are Hamilton cycles containing the subpaths $w u w' v$, $w'uwv$, and $uvww'$. In particular, we obtain the following three $uv$-paths: $uw'v$, $uwv$ and $uv$, which are all internally disjoint, as desired.
